# JavaScript: Prevent GoogleAnalytics script from being executed until my script is ready

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got this:

```
    this.$resource('api/elements/item').get().then(function (result) {
        // do something cool

    });
```

This is working fine.

But now, I would like to prevent another script (the google analytics tag) from being executed until this script is ready.

This is an example of the google analytics tag:

```
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-5xxxxxx-5"</script>
    <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-5xxxxxx-5');
    </script>
</body>
```

So is it possible to let the google script wait for my script?

Answer (score 1):

Call gtag when you are ready...

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-5xxxxxx-5"</script>
    <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    //gtag('config', 'UA-5xxxxxx-5'); <-- REMOVE THIS LINE
  </script>




this.$resource('api/elements/item').get().then(function (result) {
        // do something cool
        gtag('config', 'UA-5xxxxxx-5'); <-- CALL GTAG HERE
    });
```

Comment: As I cannot control what the user enters (and the user will probably copy&paste the Google-created tags), this is a working solution, but not the best one.

Comment: Solution is fine. But here we load script first then call.
If we need load the script inside this.$resource()    accoding to question then?

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted this from something that works for me.
I can't see any reason it won't for you too.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-5xxxxxx-5">
</script>
<script>
window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer||[];
function gtag()
{
 dataLayer.push(arguments);
}
gtag('js',new Date());
this.$resource('api/elements/item').get().then(function(result)
{
 //do something awesome
 gtag('config','UA-5xxxxxx-5');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Here we got error: VM1391:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: dataLayer is not defined

Comment: Please load your script synchronously means remove async <script src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-5xxxxxx-5">
</script>

Comment: I really have to start testing code before I post it.
I'll have a look at it.

Comment: What browser are you using please? window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer||[]; works as a stand alone statement on most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for a way to dynamically add a script tag? If so, this should do the trick:

```
this.$resource('api/elements/item').get().then(function(result) {

   // Add script tag to document
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-5xxxxxx-5';
   document.body.appendChild(script);

   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

   function gtag() {
     dataLayer.push(arguments);
   }
   gtag('js', new Date());

   gtag('config', 'UA-5xxxxxx-5');
});
```